# changing title and meta tags via jquery. will it work for crawlers?

Tags: google-search

We have a scenario where we are getting our news articles from database on runtime.
So we are chnaging our meta tags and title of the news-article page via jquery.

Will this affect the crawling mechanism?
Will the Google crawler read the dynamically created title and meta tags or not?